# Notes error: Could not open the ID file

Tags: asp.net, com, lotus-domino

I need access to **IBM Notes** from **asp.net (vb.net)**. I used **Interop.Domino.dll**. I completed my 32-bit project. I finally said to IIS that should enable 32-bit applications.

On the machine where I run my application I also install the client notes.

My problem is that when I run the application I get the following error:

[COMException (0x80040fa0): **Notes error: Could not open the file ID]**
    Domino.ISession.Initialize (String pPassword) +0
    WebApplication1.WebForm1.Page_Load (Object sender, EventArgs e) in C: \ Users \ Administrator \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2015 \ Projects \ TxControl \ WebApplication1 \ WebForm1.aspx.vb: 28
    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad (EventArgs e) +95
    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () +59
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint Boolean, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952

where I'm wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok I solved.

You have to enter in the properties of the system (windows environment variables) the path of the notes id

Comment: please put your comment as an answer, to let other users find this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter in your environment variables to the path where the notes ID